# Pushing selected objects of objects of properties from a prototype into an array

Tags: javascript, oop

My apologies for the title first.

I have this prototype which is yet to be instantiated:

The `noZoom` and the `zoom` objects **will be filled with objects on instantiation.**

I would like to push into the `propertiesToIlluminate array` all the objects within the `noZoom` objects from all properties in my `Persona` constructor.

```
function Persona() {
    this.headArea = {
        noZoom: {},
        zoom: {}
    }
    this.torsoArea = {
        noZoom: {},
        zoom: {}
    }
    this.arm = {
        noZoom: {},
        zoom: {}
    }
    this.leg = {
        noZoom: {},
        zoom: {}
    }
    this.pelvis = {
        noZoom: {},
        zoom: {}
    }
    this.abdomen = {
        noZoom: {},
        zoom: {}
    }

    this.illuminate = function() {
        var propertiesToIlluminate = [],
            prop, illuminateInternal, i = 0,
            delay = 100,
            intervalId;
        for (prop in //what to put here//) {
            propertiesToIlluminate.push(prop);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (prop in this) {
    if (this[prop].noZoom) {
        for (key in this[prop].noZoom) {
            if (this[prop].noZoom.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                propertiesToIlluminate.push(this[prop].noZoom[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns the objects within noZoom objects. I would like to get the ''values'' from within that objects so It seems that I eventually need to get just a step deeper in the iteration. Any thoughts?

Comment: I added another nested loop to get all the values within the objects.

Comment: But since `propertiesToIlluminate` is an array rather than an object, this loses the property names within the `noZoom` objects, it just gets their values.

Comment: this is because I just need to change their opacity and nothing more. The objects properties within the noZoom objects are SVG paths that are meant to have their opacity changed so I guess this is just ok.

Answer (score 1):

It might make sense keep a list of the properties, then reduce that to build the array.  Something like:

```
function Persona() {
  var properties = ["headArea", "torsoArea", "..."];
  // ...

  this.illuminate = function() {
    var self = this;
    var propertiesToIlluminate = properties.reduce(function(arr, propName) {
      var noZoom = self[propName].noZoom;
      for (var prop in noZoom) {
        if (noZoom.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          arr.push(noZoom[prop]);
        }
        return arr;
      }
    }, []);
  }
}
```

The same list could also be useful to instantiate the object to begin with, iterating over it to build the initial state.

```
for (var i=0; i<properties.list; i++) {
  this[properties[i]] = {noZoom: {}, zoom: {}};
}
```

And it could also be exposed on the prototype if desired, so other code could easily get a list of all properties.